# Using css grid with React root div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am a bit of a newbie so bear with me, I am trying to create a CSS grid where I have a header, main content and a footer.
I was trying to set the main content to auto however i think that the root div only has the height of its content and not the whole webpage so i tried:

```
#root{
  height:100%;
}
```

But it still does not work.

````
```
body{
  margin:0;
}
main{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header"
  "content"
  "footer";
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 70px;
}
Header{
  grid-area:header;
  border:1px solid black;
}
Footer{
  grid-area:footer;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#contentMain{
  grid-area:content;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not cover full height because, height is based on content we have inside div, if we want to force the middle section to take most of the space of the page we have to give its parent a height that I gave, I also added 1fr instead of auto you can learn about it in the below links,  if you want to learn about grid properties please check these links.
https://learncssgrid.com/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
main{
  display:grid;
   grid-template-areas: 
  "header"
  "content"
  "footer";
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 70px;
  height: 100vh;
}
Header{
  grid-area:header;
  border:1px solid black;
}
Footer{
  grid-area:footer;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#contentMain{
  grid-area:content;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>ss</header>
  <div class="contentMain">dd</div>
  <footer>ee</footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `#root {height:100%}` will only cause `#root` to be 100% of the ***parent*** element, in this case, `body`, which has no inherent height. So you must first set `body` to fill the viewport, then your `#root` will fill the body.

However, your content may eventually be taller than the viewport, so using `min-height` instead of `height` on the `body` element is a safer option.

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#root {
  height: 100%
}
```